# Javascript - Multiply two input fields together and display

Tags: javascript, forms, function, math, getelementbyid

The idea is that I should be able to have two fields where I input numbers, then I need to display the sum as well as the product.
I figured I would test out the product, but I keep getting a "Not a Number" error. Any help Would be great!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <form>
        First Number<br>
        <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1">
    <br>
        Second Number:<br>
        <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2">
        <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Do Maths" onclick="doMath();" />
    </form>

  <script>

      function doMath() {
          var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
          var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
          var theProduct = parseInt(my_input1) * parseInt(my_input2);  document.write(theProduct);
          document.write(theProduct);


}

  </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `my_input1` & `my_input2` are not declared anywhere.

Comment: Hi, `my_input1` and `my_input2` is not defined. `numOne` and `numTwo` should the params

Comment: I think you need `parseInt(numOne) * parseInt(numTwo)`

Answer (score 7):

You have `my_input1` and `my_input2` which are not defined.

Change this line:

`var theProduct = parseInt(my_input1) * parseInt(my_input2);  document.write(theProduct);`

This should be the correct line:

`var theProduct = parseInt(numOne) * parseInt(numTwo);  document.write(theProduct);`

And obviously if you want the sum do:

`var theTotal = parseInt(numOne) + parseInt(numTwo);`

and print it out with: `document.write(theTotal);`

**Additionally**
I wanted to add one more thing to my answer. If you are just testing, use this instead and view it in your console:

```
console.log("Product: " + theProduct);
console.log("Total: " + theTotal);
```

If you write to the document the way you are doing, you are going to remove everything, which means you'll need to refresh for every input. Not sure if you were aware of that. In any event, here's the function for reference.

```
function doMath() {
      var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
      var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
      var theProduct = parseInt(numOne) * parseInt(numTwo);
      var theTotal = parseInt(numOne) + parseInt(numTwo);
      // document.write(theProduct);
      // document.write(theTotal);
      console.log("Product: " + theProduct);
      console.log("Total: " + theTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is your correct verison of code, in the above code you have not defined my_input1 and my_input2

```js
function doMath() {
  var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  var theProduct = parseInt(numOne) * parseInt(numTwo);
  document.write(theProduct);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    First Number<br>
    <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1">
    <br> Second Number:<br>
    <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Do Maths" onclick="doMath()" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you check to calculate decimals?

Answer (score 3):

Should be like this

```js
function doMath() {
    var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
    var theProduct = parseInt(numOne) * parseInt(numTwo);    
    document.write(theProduct);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code works

```js
function doMath() {
  var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  var theProduct = parseInt(numOne) * parseInt(numTwo);
  var p = document.getElementById('theProduct');
  p.innerHTML += theProduct;
}
```

```html
<div>
  First Number<br>
  <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1"><br> Second Number:<br>
  <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Do Maths" onclick="doMath()" />
</div>
<div id="theProduct"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that everything you've writtern is okay! except that you've a typo in your code for `my_input1` should be `numOne` and same for the second input too. Check the snippet below

```js
function doMath() {
          var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
          var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
          var theProduct = parseInt(numOne) * parseInt(numTwo); 
          document.write(theProduct);


}
```

```html
<form>
        First Number<br>
        <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1">
    <br>
        Second Number:<br>
        <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2">
        <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Do Maths" onclick="doMath();" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>
  <body>

    <form>
        First Number<br>
        <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1">
    <br>
        Second Number:<br>
        <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2">
        <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Do Maths" onClick="javascript:doMath();" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <script>
    function doMath() {
          var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
          var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
          var theProduct = (parseInt(numOne) * parseInt(numTwo));
          console.log('Product:' + theProduct + '\nSum: ' + (parseInt(numOne) + parseInt(numTwo)));
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `my_input1` & `my_input2` use `parseInt(numOne, 10) * parseInt(numTwo, 10);` .Also note when using `parseInt` pass the radix

```js
function doMath() {
  var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  var theProduct = parseInt(numOne, 10) * parseInt(numTwo, 10);
  document.write(theProduct);
}
```

```html
<form>
  First Number<br>
  <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1">
  <br> Second Number:<br>
  <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Do Maths" onclick="doMath();" />
</form>
```

Comment: because there are two `document.write(theProduct);`

Comment: Lol! I removed that. :p

Answer (score 2):

You have parseInt(my_input1) - there is no my_input1. Here is the corrected working example.

```js
      function doMath() {
          var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
          var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
          var theProduct = parseInt(numOne) * parseInt(numTwo);     console.log (theProduct);
          document.getElementById('ans').innerHTML = theProduct;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <form>
        First Number<br>
        <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1">
    <br>
        Second Number:<br>
        <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2">
        <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Do Maths" onclick="doMath();" /><p/>
        Product: <span id="ans"></span>
    </form>



  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Your function here:
/*function doMath() {
  var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  var theProduct = parseInt(my_input1) * parseInt(my_input2);
  document.write(theProduct);
  document.write(theProduct);
}*/

// New Function
function doMath() {
  var stringVals = [
    document.getElementById('num1').value,
    document.getELementById('num2').value
  ];
  
  var actualVals = vals.map((val) => parseInt(val))
    .filter((val) => !isNaN(val));
    
  var sum = actualVals.reduce((currentVal, nextVal) => currentVal + nextVal, 0);
  var product = actualVals.reduce((currentVal, nextVal) => currentVal * nextVal, 1);
  
  document.getElementById('theSum').innerHTML = 'Sum: ' + sum;
  document.getElementById('theProduct').innerHTML = 'Product: ' + product;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <form>
      First Number
      <br />
      <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1">
      <br />
      Second Number:
      <br />
      <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2">
      <br /><br />
      <input type="button" value="Do Maths" onclick="doMath();" />
      <div id="theSum"></div>
      <div id="theProduct"></div>
    </form>
    
    <script>
      // Include the JS from the snippet here.
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

All other answers are good which means you defined your object name incorrectly. But I just added extra way to without working with `parseInt()` .

> If you use those input `type="number"` instead of `type="text"` then you don't need to do `ParseInt()`.

```js
function doMath() {
  var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  var theProduct = numOne * numTwo;
  document.write(theProduct);
}
```

```html
<form>
  First Number<br>
  <input id="num1" type="number" name="num1">
  <br> Second Number:<br>
  <input id="num2" type="number" name="num2">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Do Maths" onclick="doMath();" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one small change you have to do for this code :

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <form>
        First Number<br>
        <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1">
    <br>
        Second Number:<br>
        <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2">
        <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Do Maths" onclick="doMath();" />
    </form>

  <script>

      function doMath() {
          var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
          var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
          var theProduct = parseInt(numOne) * parseInt(numTwo);  
          document.write(theProduct);


}

  </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

```
   OR
```

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <form>
        First Number<br>
        <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1">
    <br>
        Second Number:<br>
        <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2">
        <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Do Maths" onclick="doMath();" />
    </form>

  <script>

      function doMath() {
          var my_input1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
          var my_input2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
          var theProduct = parseInt(my_input1) * parseInt(my_input2);  
          document.write(theProduct);


}

  </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

use the declared variable for operation to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>

        <form>
            First Number<br>
            <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1">
        <br>
            Second Number:<br>
            <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2">
            <br><br>
          <input type="button" value="Do Maths" onclick="doMath();" />
        </form>

      <script>

          function doMath() {
              var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
              var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
              var theProduct = parseInt(numOne) * parseInt(numTwo); 
              document.write(theProduct);
    }
// or
//       function doMath() {
//           var numOne = document.getElementById('num1').value;
//           var numTwo = document.getElementById('num2').value;
//           var theProduct = parseFloat(numOne) * parseFloat(numTwo); 
//           document.write(theProduct);
// }

      </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```